# iserror formulae in excel

Tags: string, excel, error-handling, find, match

In excel if I have the following

=match("abc",A:A,0)

if it errors then it throws some thing like

```
#value
```

so i tide this up by saying

=iserror((match("abc",A:A,0),"Not found",match("abc",A:A,0) )

but this seems messy code.. running the same formula twice, can this be formated better to give the same result?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2007 or later versions you can use IFERROR function to avoid repetition

`=IFERROR(MATCH("abc",A:A,0),"Not found")`

or in earlier versions you could employ COUNTIF

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,"abc"),MATCH("abc",A:A,0),"Not found")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to do this, but you could write your own VBA function:

```
Function GracefulError(varValue As Variant, strMessage As String) As Variant
    If IsError(varValue) Then
        GracefulError = strMessage
    Else
        GracefulError = varValue
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=GracefulError(match("abc",A:A,0), "Not found")
```

Comment: I was thinking of that, the only issue is that its a little less portable. but cheers for the idea :)